# Не срабатывает сеттер при изменение в DataGrid ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Есть такая проблема при использовании WPF не срабатывает свойство set{}.

Model

```
public class Layer
    {
        private string _nameLayer;
        public string NameLayer
        {
            get { return _nameLayer; }
            set { _nameLayer = value; }
        }

        private bool _showLayer;
        public bool ShowLayer
        {
            get { return _showLayer; }
            set { _showLayer = value; }
        }

        private string _colorLayer;
        public string ColorLayer { get; set; }

    }
```

Есть ViewModel класс MainViewModel реализующий свойство

```
    public Class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged   
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
                    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
public MainViewModel
{        
//в конструкторе получаем ObservableCollection<Layer> и передаем в свойство LayersCollection
}

        private ObservableCollection<Layer> _layersCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<Layer> LayersCollection
            {
                get
                {
                    return _layersCollection ?? (_layersCollection = new ObservableCollection<Layer>());
                }
                set
                {
                    _layersCollection = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LayersCollection");
                }
            }
    }
```

И View (xaml)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <mainViewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="Vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Vm}}">
    <DataGrid
        Name="Layers"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFE4DDDD"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LayersCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        VerticalGridLinesBrush="#00000000">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="*"
                Binding="{Binding NameLayer}"
                Header="Название слоя" />
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                Width="auto"
                Binding="{Binding ShowLayer}"
                Header="Видимость" />
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

При изменении во View коллекции свойство set{} не срабатывает, как решить проблему уже пробовал Model=TwoWay И UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, но изменения не приходят в сеттер.

Comment: Хотите сказать что срабатывает на сеттер в классе самой коллекции?

Comment: Ваши `Layer` `INPC` реализуют?

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, оказывается срабатывает сеттер в Model класса Layer в котором находятся свойства связанные с datagrid'ом.

Comment: Ага, вы не должны напрямую привязываться к модели, у вас должен быть VM-аналог, реализующий INPC

Comment: @Андрей речь о обновлении из `View`, `INPC` не нужен

Comment: А, ну коллекцию новую View конечно не создаст, вообще в LayersCollection можно оставить только геттер и создавать ее один раз в конструкторе

Comment: Зачем столько меток? Вы реально думаете, что кто-то подписан, например, на метку `DataGrid`?

Comment: @Андрей прошу прощения. Есть еще вопрос каким образом можно словить тогда удаление строки или добавление новой, надо же все таки как то поймать изменение свойства в ViewModel

Comment: @KJfe, при добавлении/удалении строки коллекция не перезаписывается целиком, поэтому сеттер не нужен. Нужно именно `INCC`, который реализует `ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 0):

UpdateSourceTrigger и Mode нужно ставить в байнде выводимых свойств: NameLayer и ShowLayer.

Так же не помешало бы реализовать для вашего класса Layer интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, чтобы при изменении этих свойств они изменялись и в View. 
Ну и ObservableCollection поменять на BindingList.

Comment: Интересная рекомендация, почему вы считаете что ObservableCollection нужно поменять на BindingList?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284663/difference-between-observablecollection-and-bindinglist Если в кратце, то коллекция уведомляет только об изменении самой коллекции (добавление, удаление, замена). А BindingList так же может послать уведомление о изменении значения внутри элемента, если соответствующий интерфейс реализован.

Comment: По ссылке, которую вы привели написано : "While the information in this answer is correct, any WPF users should beware: BindingList doesn't implement INotifyCollectionChanged and will cause a memory leak if bound to a control's ItemsSource property. ObservableCollection does implement the interface and won't cause any such leaks."

Comment: Возможно он и прав. Но при аккуратном использовании не будет утечки.

Comment: Upd. Возможно я всё же поторопился с советом, что стоит переходить на BindingList, похоже и коллекция, и лист уведомляют об изменении элемента. Сам я использую BindingList в проектах. Но в остальном всё так же: реализация интерфейса INPC и добавление UpdateSourceTrigger  в байнды свойств в элементе - стоит сделать.